# What's a better term to describe these "stripes" in blouse (Screen shot attached)

Tags: terminology

I am looking for the correct word for the stripes in the blouse below. Can someone help with any ideas ?

[image: blouse]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those are called **darts**.

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dart):

> **Dart**:  a stitched tapering fold in a garment

Darts are common in women's clothing to provide shaping.